Drag and Drop API re-renders causing flickering issues for uploaded images
I'm, facing flickering issues with drag and drop API.
Two things which are causing flickering:

When a image is uploaded or dropped it causes re-render due to state update.
When dragLeave & dragEnter fires which also causes re-render due to dragActive state update.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/dawn-star-73dt8g
Is there a way to avoid flickering when an item is added or removed from the state?
And also how can I avoid flickering on dragActive state change as the files stay the same.

Using CSS classes instead of state updates to handle the drag and drop visual feedback helps to minimize re-renders and you can update the state once when adding new files to reduce the number of renders
